# What does "instant wire" on LED tubes mean?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, led, lamp-tombstone

I'm replacing florescent tubes with Westgate T8 LED tubes ([T8-EZ4-18W-40K-F](http://westgatemfg.com/t8-ez4-led-tube-lamps)), which work both with or without an existing ballast (I remove the ballast when I install them). When bypassing the ballast, you have the option of wiring just one end, or both ends (I wire just one end).

One end of each tube has this warning:

> This end is short-circuit. Don't instant wire in AC.

What does "instant wire" mean? My best guess is that it's alluding to instant-start ballasts, which usually use shunted lampholders, so is it just saying to be sure to use a non-shunted tombstone at that end when bypassing the ballast?

The diagram seems to suggest that I shouldn't use that end of the tube if I have only wired one end of the luminaire, but I don't see how that relates to the text "Don't instant wire in AC".

The package insert and the manufacturer's website don't mention anything about this.

[image: Warning label with diagram and "This end is short-circuit. Don't instant wire in AC".]
[image: Package insert from Westgate]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "don't wire that end of the tube to both live and neutral -- you can have it be the live-end of the tube or the neutral-end of the tube, but not both".  Whoever wrote it was clearly not a native English speaker; also, the illustration is a much better explanation of what the deal is.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only explanation that makes sense. Apparently these tubes don't care if the lampholders are shunted or not.

Comment: I agree some of the wording on electronics products I have purchased have me scratching my head but the schematic shows they can be single ended, I would make sure to mark them so if for any reason the lamps get removed that they get put back with the correct side to the live tombstone.+